# ASP.NET MVC3 RAZOR Helpers returning plain text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

this is my code in the helper class

```
    public static string GenerateMenu(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var items = GetAllMenuItems();
        bool isIndex = false;
        var currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        StringBuilder menu = new StringBuilder();

        if (currentUrl.AbsolutePath == "/")
        {
            isIndex = true;
        }

        menu.AppendLine("<ul class=\"layout-menu\">");

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            menu.Append("<li><a ");
            if (isIndex)
            {
                if (items.First() == item)
                {
                    menu.Append("class=\"menuItemSelected\" ");
                }
            }
            if(currentUrl.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains(item.NavigateURL.ToLower()))
            {
                menu.Append("class=\"menuItemSelected\" ");
            }
            menu.Append("href=\"" + item.NavigateURL + "\">");
            menu.Append(item.Text);
            menu.Append("</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        menu.AppendLine("</ul>"); 

        return menu.ToString();
    }
```

Im displaying it using

@Html.GenerateMenu()

It renders it perfectly but not as functional objects but only as plain text, any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the return type to `MvcHtmlString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are using mvc3 you can use the HtmlString

```
public static HtmlString GenerateMenu(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        /*
          your code here 
        */ 

        return new HtmlString(menu.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your return type to `MvcHtmlString` and return a `new MvcHtmlString(menu.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest :

```
 public static MvcHtmlString GenerateMenu(this HtmlHelper helper)
 {
     ....
     return new MvcHtmlString(menu.ToString());
 }
```